# Classmethod Item Assignment

Tags: python, assignment-operator, class-method

So I have essentially created a dictionary Class that uses classmethods for all of its magic methods that looks like this:

```
class ClassDict(object):
    _items = {}

    @classmethod
    def __getitem__(cls, key):
        return cls._items[key]

    @classmethod
    def __setitem__(cls, key, val):
        cls._items[key] = val

    @classmethod
    def __len__(cls):
        return len(cls._items)

    @classmethod
    def __delitem__(cls, key):
        cls._items.__delitem__(key)

    @classmethod
    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(cls._items)
```

And so when I try to assign an item to it:

```
ClassDict['item'] = 'test'
```

I get an error saying `TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment`, but if I call the actual method, `__setitem__` like so it works fine:

```
ClassDict.__setitem__('item', 'test')
```

And this also works:

```
ClassDict().__setitem__('item', 'test')
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong here that would prevent the first example from working? Is there any way I can fix this issue?

Comment: Special methods are looked up on the *type*; it all works if you created a metaclass instead.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the behavior desired of being able to do:

```
ClassDict['item'] = 'test'
```

I had to implement the special methods as a metaclass instead as Martijn pointed out.

So my final implementation looks like this:

```
class MetaClassDict(type):
    _items = {}

    @classmethod
    def __getitem__(cls, key):
        return cls._items[key]

    @classmethod
    def __setitem__(cls, key, val):
        cls._items[key] = val

    @classmethod
    def __len__(cls):
        return len(cls._items)

    @classmethod
    def __delitem__(cls, key):
        cls._items.__delitem__(key)

    @classmethod
    def __iter__(cls):
        return iter(cls._items)


class ClassDict(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaClassDict
```